# Append byte array to pdf file c# asp.net using FileStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, byte, filestream

I am working in asp.net web application. I am trying to append byte array to pdf file using FileStream and want result as pdf file containing all byte arrays. But getting only last byte array saved in pdf. I don't want to use any external library.

Here is my code for appending bytes :

```
public void AppendByteToFile(byte[] renderedBytes)
{
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/PrintImages/file1.pdf");
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        if (stream.Length==stream.Position)
        {
            stream.Write(renderedBytes, 0, renderedBytes.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
}
```

where `rendereBytes` is rdlc object of local report rendered to pdf as follows

```
byte[] renderedBytes = report.Render("PDF", deviceInfo);
```

Thank you

Comment: You are aware that adding some `byte[]` makes the PDF invalid? Unless your added `byte[]` contains an *incremental update* according to section 7.5.6 of the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) ISO 32000-1, but a normal PDF (like your *rdlc local report rendered to pdf*) is *not* such a update.

Comment: Tank You For reply. I was not aware about information you provided about incremental update. By considering this information I guess what I am trying to do is false.

Comment: Yes. Without using *any external library*, your task is quite complex, not as easy as concatenating.